# Sed: delete all words starting with "\u" until first whitespace

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I want to remove all strings beginning with "\u" until the first whitespace or punctuation

```
INPUT
Baby gift sets avalible from \u00a37.
to \u20ac 500 persons able to meet the conditions.
\u20ac 50 million.

OUTPUT
Baby gift sets avalible from.
to 500 persons able to meet the conditions.
50 million.
```

I tried:
    `sed 's/"\u"[a-z][0-9]//g' input`

However i can't seem to match *until* whitespace.. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With using POSIX `[[:punct:]]` and space.

```
sed -e 's@\\u[^ [:punct:]]*@@g'
```

Comment: This leaves blank space before the `.` and before `50` and  `500`.

Comment: Because Q was `beginning with "\u" until the first whitespace or punctuation`

Comment: Yes, but if you look at requested Output, you will see the space is removed.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
sed 's/[  ]\\u[0-9a-f]\+\([^  0-9a-f]\)/\1/g; s/\\u[0-9a-f]\+[  ]\?//g'
```

The `[   ]` (and similar) is one space and one tab to match whitespace. The first substitute command is for the `from \u00a37.` --> `from.` special case. The second one is the most common replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply use [bash parameter expansion/search and replace](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace):

```
$ string="Baby gift sets avalible from \u00a37. to \u20ac 500 persons able to meet the conditions. \u20ac 50 million."
$ echo "${string// \\+([a-z0-9])/}"
Baby gift sets avalible from. to 500 persons able to meet the conditions. 50 million.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search and replace for multiple expressions, for eg:

```
sed -e 's/\\u[^ ]* //g' -re 's/ \\u[^ ]*([[:punct:]])/\1/' file
```

**Test**:

```
$ sed -e 's/\\u[^ ]* //g' -re 's/ \\u[^ ]*([[:punct:]])/\1/g' file
Baby gift sets avalible from.
to 500 persons able to meet the conditions.
50 million.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '{gsub(/\\u[^ .]* /,x);gsub(/ \\u[^.]*/,"")}1' file
Baby gift sets avalible from.
to 500 persons able to meet the conditions.
50 million.
```